# Is a 4" double wye on a toilet drain legit?

Tags: plumbing

I'm moving a basement bathtub drain and would like to tap into existing lines to accommodate a 2" upstairs laundry drain and prepare for another potential drain to accommodate an outside entrance scheduled for install once the frost is gone.

Wondering if the proposed double wye placement in picture is legit.

Thank you.

[image: Summary]
[image: Details]

Comment: A drain coming from the outside, that is odd and might present a problem. What a spot to have the clean out - right smack in the middle of the room. I don't  think there is any issue with the proposal but I am not read up enough on codes to say code wise, you have to wye and tee drains in whether near the clean out or far from it - the wye is the correct direction out to sewer system. Make sure you put P- traps in for those additions and also when you move the tub drain. You might need to increase the size of the air vent stack - make sure your upstairs laundry has one.